# CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE statement process more data than the underlying query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query which makes use of partition and cluster pruning on the source table to make it more efficient and process less data. This query processes a total of 169GB.

However, if I try to create a table from this query, the predicted processing amount of data displayed in the BigQuery console rises to 9.7TB, just by adding the following:

```
create or replace table `my-project`.`my_dataset`.`my_table`
    partition by date_hit
    
    OPTIONS(
      description=""""""
    )
    as (
  -- my_query
);
```

The table didn't exist previously. Why there is such a huge difference when querying the data, and when creating a table out of it? Is this something expected on BigQuery, or is it related with the source table I'm querying?